# How to use a single JFrame and display Multiple JPanels based on a Action Listener?

Tags: java, swing

Im building a math testing program for class. A user enters a username, the number of problems, and the number of digits. The program spits out a problem and the user answers in a textfield on that page.

Is there a way to make a default page that loads different JPanels based on a button action?
Additionaly, Can you store Jpanels in an arrayList and store the inputs?

```
ArrayList <JPanel> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; actionListener == true ; i++){

    default_JFrame().add(arrList.get(i));
}
```

Are there any general best practices for Java Swing?

Comment: You can swap JPanels easily using a [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). As for storing an `ArrayList<JPanel>`, of course this can be done, but often its better to separate the program's logic from its view, and instead store a List of questions.

Comment: `The program spits out a problem and the user answers in a textfield on that page.` - why do you need multiple panels? Just update a JLabel with the text of the new question.

Comment: @camickr I realized that the longer I tinkered with Java. Its less about updating frames and more about the information on the screen.
Thanks for the insight